# Always charm a Monster discarding my whole hand? having 4+cards

Tags: munchkin

As a Wizard I have 5 cards in my hand. In order to charm the monster am I obligated to discard my whole hand of 5 cards or could I discard just 3 or 4 cards from my hand? It is not clear that you always have to discard your whole hand.

[image: Wizard]

Answer (score 4):

If the card says you may discard your whole had that is what it means. It doesn't matter if you have the minimum of 3 cards or 5 cards the price is discarding everything.

Answer (score 4):

It very clearly says you may discard your whole hand, meaning if you want to use the charm monster ability you must discard every card in your hand. In this case that means all 5 cards. The reason it says 3 cards minimum is to let you know you can't use this action if you only have one or two cards in your hand by discarding them, or discarding no cards from an empty hand which is legal in some games. If it had meant for you to only discard three cards, it would have said to discard three cards.